# C# console cannot launch on MonoDevelop 2.4

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

I tried to load a New solution > C# > Console project, while pressing Ctrl+F5, it does not run or showing anything, do I need to install .NET SDK?

I could launch the GTK# windows create on my own.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug.

Right click your project, do Options, go to Run: General, and turn off "Run on external console".

Comment: Can see on the output, when try to get the commandline to display, it doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, its not a full console, so you can't give it input.  That is the reason for the new external console support.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because your program isn't doing anything, so the console window closes instantly.

Try adding `Console.ReadKey()` to the `Main` method.

Comment: Build successful. No error, no warning and 0 message. No showing anything.